# how to get the url to usefor a private path

Tags: 8, stream-wrappers

if I have a file saved in private:://somefile.txt  , what function can I use in drupal to give me the external URL to access that?

I tried `PrivateStream::getExternalUrl()`
but I get this error

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Drupal\mymodule\myservice::getTarget() in /opt/DrupalSites/drupal-wcms-migration/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StreamWrapper/PrivateStream.php on line 50`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `PrivateStream::getExternalUrl()` directly because it's not a static function; it needs an instantiated stream before you can call `getExternalUrl()` on it.

You can retrieve it via the stream wrapper manager's [`getViaUri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StreamWrapper%21StreamWrapperManagerInterface.php/function/StreamWrapperManagerInterface%3A%3AgetViaUri/8.5.x) method:

```
$stream = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaUri('private:://somefile.txt');
$stream->getExternalUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call getExternalUrl() directly either, you should just use file_create_url('private://somefile.txt').

There is no OOP version of it yet, this is being worked on.